# .htaccess remove trailing slash before redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble with removing the trailing slash when i redirect to another page.

See my code:

```
Redirect /contact  example.com/page
```

When I run the code above it redirects me to example.com/page/ with a trailing slash.

I would like to know how I can remove the trailing slash from the url.

Full .htaccess:

```
# All explanations you could find in .htaccess.sample file

Redirect /configurator.html /box.html
Redirect /catalog/category/view/s/blog/id/9 http://www.example.nl/blog

Redirect /contact/index/ http://www.example.com/contact.html
Redirect /contact.html/post http://www.example.com/contact.html

DirectoryIndex index.php
   <IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value memory_limit 768M
   php_value max_execution_time 18000
   php_flag session.auto_start off
   php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 768M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have other directives in htaccess?

Comment: @starkeen i've added the full .htaccess content to the question.

Comment: look in your browser networking tool. Maybe it is a double redirect. As an example WordPress will always look for the trailing slash and add it, when it is missing

Comment: @Sysix i don't see a double redirect in my networking tool. I'm using Magento. Dont' know if Magento has also some kind of system for this.